# Created DbConfiguration dynamically in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.4.4 in .NET 5, and want to associate a `MyDbConfiguration` with a `MyDbContext`.  However, the only way to do this appears to declare `MyDbContext` with a `DbConfigurationType` attribute.  For example:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext
{
}
```

But an attribute is static, and I need to create `MyDbConfiguration` dynamically, via a dependency injection framework.  Is there any way to do this?